Unique representation of elements in $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$
Question: Show that any element $a \in \hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ has a unique representation $a = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_{n}n!$ where $c_{n} \in \{0, 1, \dots, n\}$.
My attempt: I have proven earlier that $\hat{\mathbb{Z}} \cong \varprojlim_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z} / m! \mathbb{Z}$, so it suffices to show that there exists a bijection between the set of infinite formal series $M = \{ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_{n}n! \mid c_{n} \in \{0, 1, \dots, n\} \}$ and the inverse limit $\varprojlim_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z} / m! \mathbb{Z}$.
I thought about explicitly constructing a map and its inverse to conclude that there is a bijection. Namely I thought of
$\phi : M \rightarrow \varprojlim_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z} / m! \mathbb{Z} : \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_{n}n! \mapsto \left( \sum_{n=1}^{m-1} c_{n}n! \right) \mod m!$,
sending an infinite formal series to a sequence of residue classes. I was wondering if this is the right approach, and how I would go about constructing the inverse map of $\phi$. Any help is appreciated!

Yes, this works. You can write down the inverse pretty explicitly. Given $\sum_{n=1}^{m-1} c_n n! \bmod m!$, think about what information you learn about the digits $c_n$ after further reducing $\bmod 2!, 3!, 4!, \dots $.

Thank you for your response @QiaochuYuan. Since we have that a coefficient $c_{m}$ is given by $c_{m} = \frac{1}{m!}\left( \sum_{n=1}^{m} c_{n}n! - \sum_{n=1}^{m-1} c_{n}n! \right)$, we can define an inverse map by sending a sequence to the infinite formal series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \overline{s}{m+2} - \overline{s}{m + 1}$ where $\overline{s}{m+1} = \left( \sum{n=1}^{m-1} c_{n}n! \right) \mod m!$. Is that correct?

Im actually not sure if this works..
